# Disagreement between p-value and confidence interval hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a question about a disagreement between a hypothesis test through a p-value and a test through a confidence interval. I thought they weren't supposed to disagree.

The problem is the following (I think its from a textbook from Rice Uni):

- > "Registered nurses earned an average annual salary of 69,110. For that same year, a survey was conducted of 41 California registered nurses to determine if the annual salary is higher than $69,110 for California nurses. The sample average was 71,121 with a sample standard deviation of 7,489."

**Issue**: based on a 0.05 significance , we reject the null that the nurses average anual salary is 69110 because the p-value is 0.0466 but based on a 95% confidence Interval we don't reject it because the interval is given approx. by:  (68,757; 73,485) . 
What's going on here?

Comment: Pay attention to the difference between one-tailed and two-tailed intervals.

Comment: Of course, thus , for a 0.05% hypothesis test I need to use a 90% C.I. and so on, I'm I right?

Comment: Yes, provided that by "0.05%" you really meant 5% :-) and by "hypothesis test" you meant a *one-sided* test, as in the question.

Comment: Yes whuber! that was what I meant! thank you so much for sharing your knowledge :)